# Issue creating user-generated buttons in maya

Tags: python, list, function, button, maya

I'm trying to create a script for maya that essentially makes quick selection sets as indices inside a list.

I've got it storing and loading the information with buttons that already exist, but I want the user to be able to generate new buttons if the default number of selection sets is insufficient.

I currently have a button that generates new buttons. If only generating one button, it works fine.

My first problem: If you generate a second button, the first generated button then uses the same list index as the second generated button.

e.g. I create a new button (button 4). It stores and loads the selection without issue.
I create another new button (button 5). Now button 4 will store and load as though it were button 5, as will button 5 itself.

My second problem: If you have already stored a selection, you can not create a new button.

My code so far is:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

favsWindowName = 'favsWindow'
numButtons = 4

def favsWindowUI():
    if mc.window(favsWindowName, exists=True):
        mc.deleteUI(favsWindowName, wnd=True)
    mc.window(favsWindowName, title="Favourites", resizeToFitChildren=True, bgc=(0.20, 0.50, 0.50), s=True)
    mc.rowColumnLayout(nr=1)
    mc.button("newSet", label="New Selection Set", c=("newButton()"))
    mc.rowColumnLayout(nr=2)
    mc.button("Load1", label="Load Slot 1", w=200, c=("Load(1)"))
    mc.button("Sel1", label="Select Slot 1", w=200, c=("Sel(1)"))
    mc.button("Load2", label="Load Slot 2", w=200, c=("Load(2)"))
    mc.button("Sel2", label="Select Slot 2", w=200, c=("Sel(2)"))
    mc.button("Load3", label="Load Slot 3", w=200, c=("Load(3)"))
    mc.button("Sel3", label="Select Slot 3", w=200, c=("Sel(3)"))
    mc.showWindow()

selList = []

def Load(favNum):
    try:
        # if a selection has already been loaded for this button, replace it.
        selList[favNum-1] = mc.ls(sl=True)
    except IndexError:
        try:
            #if the previous index exists
            if selList[favNum-2] > 0:
                # if a selection has not yet been loaded for this button, create it.
                selList.append(mc.ls(sl=True))
        except IndexError:
            # if the previous index doesn't exist 'cause this is the first entry
            if favNum == 1:
                selList.append(mc.ls(sl=True))
            else:
                #if the previous index doesn't exist, raise an error.
                mc.error("Load the previous selection first!")


def Sel(favNum):
    try:
        # if a selection has been loaded for this button, select it.
        mc.select(selList[favNum-1], r=True)
    except IndexError:
        # if no selection has been loaded for this button, raise an error.
        mc.error("No selection loaded.")

def newButton():
    #generate a new button set using the next available index.
    global numButtons
    mc.button("Load"+str(numButtons), label="Load Slot "+str(numButtons), w=200, c=("Load(numButtons-1)"))
    mc.button("Sel"+str(numButtons), label="Select Slot "+str(numButtons), w=200, c=("Sel(numButtons-1)"))
    numButtons += 1

favsWindowUI()
```

I'm also not sure why with the generated buttons I need to use `Load(numButtons-1)` as opposed to `Load(numButtons)` in the newButton function... but it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar issue, I'll post the solution that we (I and some friends from school) figured out.
Using `partial` resolved the issue of all newly generated buttons using the same index.
The other issue (not being able to generate new buttons after a selection was loaded) was due to the parent for the new buttons not being set. We gave one of our `rowColumnLayout`'s a name and set it as the parent using the `setParent` maya command.
To see that in context, refer to the code below.

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from functools import partial

favsWindowName = 'favsWindow'

def favsWindowUI():
    if mc.window(favsWindowName, exists=True):
        mc.deleteUI(favsWindowName, wnd=True)
    mc.window(favsWindowName, title="Favourites", resizeToFitChildren=True, bgc=(0.20, 0.50, 0.50), s=True)
    mc.rowColumnLayout(nr=2)
    mc.textFieldGrp('btnName', tx='new button name')
    mc.button("newSet", label="New selection Set", c=(newButton))
    mc.rowColumnLayout('selectionLayout', nc=2)
    mc.showWindow()

selList = {}

def load(favNum, *args):
    # Load the selection into the dictionary entry
    selList[favNum] = mc.ls(sl=True)


def sel(favNum, *args):
    try:
        # if a selection has been loaded for this button, select it.
        mc.select(selList[favNum], r=True)
    except IndexError:
        # if no selection has been loaded for this button, raise an error.
        mc.error("No selection loaded.")


def newButton(*args):
    buttonName = mc.textFieldGrp('btnName', q=True, tx=True)
    mc.setParent('selectionLayout')
    if buttonName != 'new button name':
        if mc.button("load"+str(buttonName), exists=True, q=True):
            mc.error("A selection set named %s already exists." % buttonName)
        mc.button("load"+str(buttonName), label="Load Slot "+str(buttonName), w=200, c=(partial(load,buttonName)))
        mc.button("sel"+str(buttonName), label="Select Slot "+str(buttonName), w=200, c=(partial(sel,buttonName)))
        mc.textFieldGrp('btnName', tx='new button name', e=True)
    else:
        mc.error("Rename the button first.")


favsWindowUI()
```